# Attribute in Tridion Schema Design

Tags: xsd, schema, tridion

In SDL Tridion Schema design view, there is no way you can add Attribute to an element.

This seems like a design decision. Anybody knows anything regarding the reason behind this? Do you find this limiting your freedom of designing schema?

This is more important if you are doing migration where you have attribute in your old schema. You can always rewrite your schema to not use attribute, but it means you have to do the mapping between the old and new schema.

Of course, you can add attribute using the Source view, however, you will no longer to edit the schema again using the Design view.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simply that it would be almost impossible to design a UI to edit XML based on any W3C schema. So a subset of Scema was created for use in the UI.

However, in 12 years of working with Tridion, I have yet to create a complex schema for content. You should be OK.

Comment: There are a lot of good tools to edit XML based on any W3C schema (it should be possible to make it work inside  browser), we are using Authentic http://www.altova.com/authentic/wysiwyg-xml.html  form XMLSpy for this purpose (Of course, you will need StyleVision to create the SPS file first.). Maybe Tridion should invest more time on coming out with one.  I understand I can always change my legacy schema, but that would make all my legacy content invalid. The best solution is to re-use the legacy schema.

Comment: Those tools you mention are not usable by your average content author.  Schemas designed in such a way that they make sense to authors are worth so much more than the time you might save by keeping your old Schema.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you include a custom XSD you cannot edit this and content based on it within the normal SDL Tridion interface.

It is possible to create an embedded schema, which you can include into your 'master' schema as an embedded schema field.   There is also the possibility to have embedded fields inside embedded fields.  Finally there is also the functionality to enable multiple repeating of any field, so I  suspect you won't have any problems defining your schema / data model.